# How to create a listener for RBlockingQueue using redisson?

Tags: redis, redisson

In one of my services I am adding to the queue:

```
RBlockingQueue<String> queue = redissonClient.getBlockingQueue("ABC");
            queue.add(receivedTask.toString());
```

And in the 2nd service I am connecting to the same redis instance and want to read/pop from the queue once a new element gets added from the 1st service, something like this:

```
RBlockingQueue<String> queue = redisClient.getRedissonClient().getBlockingDeque("ABC");
        System.out.println("received: " +  queue.poll(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

I was earlier dealing with RTopic and it was working fine but the use case has changed and now have to use RQueue instead. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found what I was doing wrong.
Should be using subscribeOnElements(): it notifies the listener and polls the new element which can be accessed.

```
queue.subscribeOnElements((msg) -> {
//code
});
```